# CDF of a random vector

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

I am reading a book that in one page it talks about cdf of a random vector. This is from the book:

> Given $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$, each of the random variables $X_1, ... ,X_n$ can be characterized from a probabilistic point of view by its cdf.

However the cdf of each coordinate of a random vector does not completely describe the probabilistic behaviour of the whole vector. For instance, if $U_1$ AND $U_2$ are two independent random variables with the same cdf $G(x)$, the vectors $X=(X_1, X_2)$ defined respectively by $X_1=U_1$, $X_2=U_2$ and $X_1=U_1$, $X_2=U_1$ have each of their coordinates with the same cdf, and they are quite different.

My question is:

From the very last paragraph, it says $U_1$ and $U_2$ are coming from the same c.d.f. And then they define $X=(X_1, X_2)$, but they say $X=(X_1, X_2)$ is different from $X=(X_1, X_1)$. I don't really understand why the two $X$ are different.

(i.e. I don't understand why $X=(X_1, X_2)$ and $X=(X_1, X_1)$ are different). Isn't $X_1$ the same as $X_2$, so it doesn't matter whether you put two $X_1$ to form $X=(X_1, X_1)$ or put one $X_1$ and one $X_2$ to form $X=(X_1, X_2)$. Shouldn't they be the same? why does the author says they are "quite different"?

Could someone explain why they are different?

Comment: I throw a fair coin and record its outcome with a binary indicator ($X_1$).  You throw a fair coin and similarly record its outcome ($X_2$).  Is it not obvious those two random variables differ?  Nature will not guarantee they always produce the same result, that's for sure!  Yet they have identical distributions and are independent.

Comment: There are two simple but quite different ways to approach this (well, there are more than two, but I'll mention two). (i) by actually sampling $U_1,U_2$ and just looking at the density of points for the two definitions of $X$ (what software do you have available? Excel? Matlab? R? C?); (ii) Proceeding directly from definitions (i.e. do you know what the definition of the cdf is?).

Comment: The components of $(X_1, X_1)$ are not independent (unless $X$ is almost surely constant) while you have defined the components of $(X_1, X_2)$ to be independent.  So their joint distributions must be different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us take the simplest example of Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac12$.  The value of the (joint) CDF $F_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)$ of $X_1$ and $X_2$
is the
total probability mass in the southwest quadrant with northeast corner $(x,y)$

- If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two *independent* Bernoulli random variables,
  then we have *four* probability masses of $\frac14$ sitting at 
  $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$, and $(1,1)$.  Hence
  $$F_{X_1,X_2}\left(\frac12,\frac12\right) = \frac14.$$
- If $X_2 = 1-X_1$,
  then we have *two* probability masses of $\frac12$ sitting at 
  $(1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  Hence
  $$F_{X_1,X_2}\left(\frac12,\frac12\right) = 0.$$
- If $X_2 = X_1$, then we have *two* probability masses of $\frac12$ sitting at 
  $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.  Hence
  $$F_{X_1,X_2}\left(\frac12,\frac12\right) = \frac12.$$

Thus, the *joint* CDF of $X_1$ and $X_2$ *does* depend on what
kind of relationship (if any) they have with each other, and just
knowing the common CDF of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (these are *marginal* CDFs)
tells us nothing about the behavior the joint CDF.

Comment: thanks. I think I understand now. Sorry it has been a year lol haha.

Answer (score 1):

Random objects can have the same distribution and be almost surely different. Take a look:

[Can two random variables have the same distribution, yet be almost surely different?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/can-two-random-variables-have-the-same-distribution-yet-be-almost-surely-differ/24939#24939)

Answer (score 0):

The key is the difference between joint and marginal distributions. When the book talks about the cdf of a random vector $X=(X_1,X_2)$ they mean the function $$F_X(x_1,x_2):=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2 ).$$ As you probably know, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, this equals $$F_{X_1}(x_1)F_{X_2}(x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)\mathbb{P}(X_2\leq x_2),$$ but, on the other hand if they are not independent, we cannot separate the joint probability into their product like that per definition of dependence/independence.

Indeed, in your example where $X_1=X_2$, we have that $$F_X(x_1,x_2):=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2 )=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,X_1\leq x_2 )=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq \min(x_1, x_2))\neq\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x_2).$$

Again, the key is that just because two variables have the same marginal distribution, this does not mean their joint distributions with another variable are the same.